# Find consecutive alphabetical characters in string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement where I need to find the consecutive alphabetical characters in the string in Oracle SQL.
I have tried regular expressions but it is not working.

Table Name - Test_Dummy(var_col)

```
Values in Var_Col 
Test
Test1
Tesssst
TTTTest
ABCDTest

Select * from test_dummy where regexp_like(var_col, '[A-Za-z]{5,}');
```

The output I am getting is all the strings with more than 5 characters.

I used below regexp to get the repeated characters -

```
Select * from test_dummy where regexp_like(var_col,'(.+1)\1{3,}?');
```

Result :

```
TTTTest
Tesssst
```

I need to find consecutive data i.e. ABCDTest

Comment: You said what you have, what you tried, what you got, but you never said what you **expect** as result based on sample data.

Comment: Why do you want **ABCD**Te**st**, but not Tesss**st**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string into individual characters and then use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` (from Oracle 12 onwards) to perform row-by-row pattern matching to look for consecutive ASCII values:

```sql
SELECT value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT MIN(lvl) AS start_pos
         FROM   (
           SELECT LEVEL AS lvl,
                  SUBSTR(t.value, LEVEL, 1) AS ch
           FROM   DUAL
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(t.value)
         )
         MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
           ORDER BY lvl
           MEASURES
             FIRST(lvl) AS lvl
           PATTERN (first_row consecutive{3,})
           DEFINE first_row   AS (ch BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' OR ch BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z'),
                  consecutive AS (ch BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' OR ch BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z')
                                 AND ASCII(PREV(ch)) + 1 = ASCII(ch)
         )
         HAVING MIN(lvl) > 0
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'Test'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test1'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tesssst'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TTTTest'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCDTest' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Testuvwxyz' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| ABCDTest |
| Testuvwxyz |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zXe8Agmb)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for 3 consecutive characters located at the beginning of the string (that's what I understood while reading what you wrote), then this might be one option. Read comments within code.

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (col)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'Test' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'Test1' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 'Tesssst' FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 'TTTTest' FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 'ABCDTest' FROM DUAL
 13         UNION ALL
 14         SELECT 'efgwhatever' FROM DUAL),
```

Query begins here:

```
 15     temp
 16     AS
 17        -- split COL into separate characters, find their ASCII values
 18        (SELECT col,
 19                ASCII (SUBSTR (col, COLUMN_VALUE, 1)) val,
 20                ASCII (SUBSTR (col, COLUMN_VALUE + 1, 1)) next_val,
 21                COLUMN_VALUE CV
 22           FROM test
 23                CROSS JOIN
 24                TABLE (
 25                   CAST (MULTISET (    SELECT LEVEL
 26                                         FROM DUAL
 27                                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (col)) AS SYS.odcinumberlist)))
 28    -- return COLs whose first 3 characters are sparated by only one ASCII value
 29    SELECT col
 30      FROM temp
 31     WHERE CV <= 2
 32  GROUP BY col
 33    HAVING SUM (next_val - val) = 2;

COL
-----------
ABCDTest
efgwhatever

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get better performance this way: you scan the string by recursive CTE calculating the number of times your condition between chars is met and stop the recursion as soon as condition is met:

```
with table_name(id, value) as (
SELECT 1, 'Test'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Test1'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Tesssst'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'TTTTest'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'ABCDTest' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Testuvwxyz' FROM DUAL
),
cte(id, lvl, value, ch, flag) as (
    select id, 1, value, ascii(substr(value, 1, 1)), 0 from table_name 

    union all
    
    select c.id, lvl+1, c.value, ascii(substr(c.value, lvl+1,1)), 
        case when c.ch+1 = ascii(substr(c.value, lvl+1,1)) then flag + 1 else 0 end
    from cte c
    where lvl < length(c.value) and flag < 3 
)
select value from cte where flag = 3
;
```

Comment: It's even possible to scan from end to start at the same time and thus limit the recursion to half the size of the string.